# Display static resource image from formula field on visualforce page.

Tags: visualforce, static-resources, images

Ok, I have a formula field that references a static resource image. This formula field displays correctly within the standard Salesforce UI but when I try and add the field to a custom visualforce field I cannot get it to display. I have tried every bit of syntax that I can find but I am not hitting on the correct one. Can anyone help?

Formula Field (Status_Icon__c):

```
IF(
Auto_Status__c = "Expired",
IMAGE("/resource/Expired","! Expired"),

IF(
Auto_Status__c = "Current",
IMAGE("/resource/Current","! Current"),
""
)
)
```

VF:

```
            <apex:column style="align:center;text-align:center;">
                <apex:facet name="header">Status</apex:facet>
                <apex:image url="{!Lic.Status_Icon__c}" height="50px"/><br />
                <apex:outputtext >{!Lic.Status_Icon__c}</apex:outputtext>
            </apex:column>
```

Sample from VF page:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable "escaping", a feature designed to prevent script injections. Since you control the formula, you can disable this automatic protection:

```
<apex:outputtext escape="false" value="{!Lic.Status_Icon__c}" />
```